Business idea: chemistry labs open to the general public with entrance on the street
I have the following business idea:
What if we had general chemistry or biology labs open to the general public with entrance on the street.
Laypeople could view lab material on their cellphone and walk in to run an experiment.

the value to the customer, would be:

enjoyment

entertainment

learning

time filler

idea generation (and, time, employment, generator


Why is this not available?
Why is this not possible?
Thanks.

I’m voting to close this question because it’s not about economics.

Lab safety standards and the price of equipment/materials. That's one of the reasons.
Two notes on this.
First: To quote Mythbusters "For something to be scientific experiment, it is not enough to blow stuff up, you have to record results as well."
Enjoyment/entertainment? This would be an expensive form of fun with very small market niche. That's the second reason and its tied to the first one. You need funding. Your competition would be schools and youtube.
Second note:
If you would change your premise a little, I think that you would like the concept of FabLab, an assembly of people, materials, machines and knowledge which would enable one to build and test (almost) anything. Its the community that's important, though. Its your concept expanded to be able to actually create things, not just make experiments for amusement.
See more here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fab_lab
